# Can't output log in real time in a pyqt slot

Tags: python, pyqt5, signals-slots

I created a QPushButton widget and a QTextEdit widget, and what I want is that once I click the button, the system will execute an external program, and output log to the QTextEdit widget.

The problem is the log can't be continually sent to the QTextEdit widget. It is sent all at once after the external program done. Why?

This is my code:

```
class Window(Qwidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        ...
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.onStart)  
        ...
    def onStart(self):
        # keep sending log in this solt, similar to my external program
        for i in range(10000):
            self.logger.debug(str(i))
```

And I have already redirect `self.logger.debug()` to sys.stdout, and output log to QTextEdit widget in a thread.

```
class myThread(QThread):
    printText = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myThread,self).__init__(parent)

    def write(self, output):
        self.printText.emit(output)

    def flush(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(.1)
```

When I click the button, pyqt get stuck in loop `for i in range(10000)` and display nothing. After a few seconds, all the output log displays all at once, instead displays in real time.

Comment: There is nothing in your code example that runs in a separate thread - it all runs in the main thread, and hence will block the main event-loop.

Answer (score 0):

As ekhumoro's suggestion, I put the loop in a thread:

```
def onStart(self):
    _thread.start_new_thread(self.myLoop, ())
def myLoop(self):
    for i in range(10000):
        self.logger.debug(i)
```

`_thread` module meets my functional requirement and works well here. If your needs to communicate with other threads in `myLoop()`, `threading` and `queue` are more powerful.